# MEF ioc, use interface interception of method arguments in asp.mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

All my services have interfaces, i basically just put an interface in a mvc controller's constructor, and then mef injects the proper concrete type.

Example:

```
[Export(typeof(IAccountService))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
   .. methods...
}
```

Is there a way to use this interface, to use an interceptor and log method calls, including their argument values.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you want to accomplish. Give us some code example.